# iOS download each file separately or in one archive

Tags: ios, download

I'm working on an iOS app where I need to regularly "push" new levels to device. Level is a HTML5 page with images, javascript and css files. I need all level's files to be cached locally before level can be played by a user. Each level is about 1.5MB. I'm thinking of archiving entire level's folder with HTML, images, css and js into one zip archive, downloading this zip and then unarchiving it on device. But maybe it is more efficient to download each file separately, because they can be downloaded concurrently?

This is my first iOS app and I'm not really sure how to do it correctly. So the question is: what is the best way to asynchronously download an entire folder from a server and then trigger a callback when all files are downloaded (keeping in mind that user can close the app or lose connection in the middle of download)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since most users are actually on slow 3G connections, compressed archive downloads will be much faster (and cheaper for them) and will probably saturate their connection entirely. Doing it concurrently would just make all the transfers slower as they're forced to share the same limited connection. Doing it in one go also avoids the headaches associated with one of the many transfers file transfer failing for example.

Comment: This is the right answer. Also, consider using ASIHTTPRequest for your requests if you want more advanced features/ease of use.

Comment: I decided to choose this approach (as opposed to the answer below) because after download I want to store all files separately so that I can update them individually. Thanks for suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

I find that compressing is actually slower because the devices take just as long to uncompress as they do downloading. As mentioned look into ASIHTTPRequest using this you can say 'get the page and all it's resources' 
http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/Setup-instructions

```
- (IBAction)downloadLevel:(NSURL *)levelURL
{
    // Assume request is a property of our controller
    // First, we'll cancel any in-progress page load
    [self.request setDelegate:nil];
    [self.request cancel];

    [self setRequest:[ASIWebPageRequest requestWithURL:levelURL]];
    [self.request setCompletionBlock:^{
        //code in here runs when the request finishes
    }];

    [self.request setFailedBlock:^{
        //code in here runs when the request fails
    }];

    // Tell the request to embed external resources directly in the page
    [self.request setUrlReplacementMode:ASIReplaceExternalResourcesWithData];

    // It is strongly recommended you use a download cache with ASIWebPageRequest
    // When using a cache, external resources are automatically stored in the cache
    // and can be pulled from the cache on subsequent page loads
    [self.request setDownloadCache:[ASIDownloadCache sharedCache]];

    // Ask the download cache for a place to store the cached data
    // This is the most efficient way for an ASIWebPageRequest to store a web page
    [self.request setDownloadDestinationPath:
     [[ASIDownloadCache sharedCache] pathToStoreCachedResponseDataForRequest:self.request]];

    [self.request startAsynchronous];
}
```

More documentation can be found here
http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/ASIWebPageRequest
and here
http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use
It's all a very easy read.

Comment: Endy, thanks for the suggestion. I heard that ASIHTTPRequest is not maintained anymore and that it has some problems on ios5. Do you know anything about this?

Comment: It is true that ASIHTTPRequest is no longer maintained however, I have never had any major issues with it and i've been using it heavily (relying on it for all network connections) for about 7-8 months now. In the unlikely event that you do have an issue all of the files are actually very easy to read through and follow.